# Spark SQL nested arrays and beans support

Tags: java, apache-spark

Each hour I got some value updates as a new DataFrame. I have to reduce DataFrames in order to deduplicate entities and to track history of value updates. Because reduce logic is too complex, I'm converting DataFrames to JavaRDD, reducing and than converting JavaRDD back to DataFrame.

The issue is that I have to use nested data structures after reduce.

### Question

I've read the [inferring the schema using reflaction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.3/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection), but still it's not clear for me:

*Does Spark SQL supports only nested arrays of primitives or nested arrays of beans too?*

*Why does Case 1 code doesn't work while Case 2 works?*

### Case 1

From the following code I got:

> scala.MatchError: History(timestamp=1970-01-01 00:00:00.0,
>   value=10.0) (of class com.somepackage.History)

So I can conclude that Spark does not support nested array of beans. *But see Case 2.*

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Entity implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private History[] history;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class History implements Serializable {

    private Timestamp timestamp;
    private Double value;
}

JavaRDD<Entity> rdd = JavaSparkContext
    .fromSparkContext(spark().sparkContext())
    .parallelize(asList(
        new Entity(1, new History[] {
           new History(new Timestamp(0L), 10.0)
        })
    ));
spark()
    //EXCEPTION HERE!
    .createDataFrame(rdd, Entity.class)
    .show();
```

### Case 2

On the other hand, the next code works correct with nested arrays of beans:

```
Dataset<Entity> dataSet = spark()
    .read()
    .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
    .schema(fromJson("/data/testSchema.json"))
    .json(getAbsoluteFilePath("data/testData.json"))
    .as(Encoders.bean(Entity.class));

JavaRDD<Entity> rdd = dataSet
    .toJavaRDD()
    .mapToPair(o -> tuple(RowFactory.create(o.getId()), o))
    .reduceByKey((o1, o2) -> o2)
    .values()
    .saveAsTextFile("output.json");

-------

private String getAbsoluteFilePath(String relativePath) {
    return this
        .getClass()
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResource("")
        .getPath() + relativePath;
}

private StructType fromJson(String pathToSchema) {
    return (StructType) StructType.fromJson(
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                Resources.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToSchema)
            )
        )
            .lines()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))
    );
}
```

*testData.json*

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "history": [
      {
        "timestamp": "2018-10-29 23:11:44.000",
        "value": 12.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "history": [
      {
        "timestamp": "2018-10-30 14:43:05.000",
        "value": 13.2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

*testSchema.json*

```
{
  "type": "struct",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "integer",
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "history",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "elementType": {
          "type": "struct",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "timestamp",
              "type": "timestamp",
              "nullable": true,
              "metadata": {}
            },
            {
              "name": "value",
              "type": "double",
              "nullable": true,
              "metadata": {}
            }
          ]
        },
        "containsNull": true
      },
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? In particular did you get an answer to the question "Does Spark SQL supports only nested arrays of primitives or nested arrays of beans too?"

Comment: @SiLaf see "Case 2" working example. You can use array of struct types